# C# NumericUpDown Button Arrows

Tags: c#, winforms, button, numeric

Hello I am trying to create a NumericUpDown Button but I can't see any events referring to which button is pressed (Up or Down I mean). How can I check which button the user pressed?

Comment: `OnChange` may hold the answer

Comment: What sort of application is it? web/win? and can you post the relevent code

Comment: @Izzy It is a windows form application. I don't have the code yet. Just the code that was already generated when I dragged and dropped the button in the designer. I am just searching for the event listener that will determine if the user pressed the up or the down key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var oldValue = numericUpDown1.Value;
        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var newValue=  numericUpDown1.Value;

          if (oldValue < newValue))
          {
              // this is up button
          }
          else
          {
              //this is down button
          }
        }
```

this may help you. I didnt write %100 correct for example you have to convert new value to int and blabla. But logic is that. You have to subscribe to numericupdown valuechanged event

Comment: Using this methodology, don't forget to update your oldValue at the end of the valueChange event.

Answer (score 1):

use NumericUpDown.ValueChanged Event and save current value into local field and check weather its greater or less to local field

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. I wanted to know if the value came from a text entry or a button. Once I programmed the mouse click I could set a parameter so that the ValueChanged event would know.

```
   private void nud1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X <= nud1.Controls[1].Width+1) {
           // Click is in text area
        }
        else {
           if (e.Y <= nud1.Controls[1].Height / 2)
              // Click is on Up arrow
           else
              // Click is on Down arrow
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only the textarea part is working, if you click on the buttons, the increment/decrement function works and not your function. Only if you click 1px next to the buttons.