# How to differentiate mouse events for NumericUpDown controls edit box and arrow buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

There are two controls in the NumericUpDown control.One is the up down buttons and the second is an edit box.Position zero of the NumericUpDown collection of it's controls is the up down buttons.Position one is the edit box.

I have numericupdown control in my form with MouseUp and MouseDown events enabled. The events are firing,
* When  i click the edit box
* When i click the up/down arrow buttons

i want to discard the edit box event. I should act on arrow buttons event. How to differentiate the events? whether the event is from edit box or arrow buttons?

Thanks.

Comment: The DataGridView has a HitTest() method that lets you do something similar but I don't know how you would begin to implement it for NumericUpDown controls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You might be able to handle all mouse clicks and pragmatically determine if it's on a  NumericUpDown's arrow buttons by checking control position and size. Wouldn't be the prettiest work around but it might get the job done.

Comment: Thanks @JacobHuckins Is the MouseClick property listen for up/down arrow button click?. I tried the solution in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52994483/12027865. But i dont see the event for up/down arrow click

Comment: That looks like a good solution. What do you mean by 'don't see the event'? Did you add the event handler to the control?

Comment: Yes. The event is fired for editbox click but not for up/down arrow buttons click.

Comment: The NumericUpDown.Click event woks for me but not the NumericUpDown.MouseClick event.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to create a new control (MyNumericUpDown), and override the UpButton/DownButton methods. You can trigger custom events from this methods. Then in your code you can attach to this custom events

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public event EventHandler UpDownClick;
    public event EventHandler UpClick;
    public event EventHandler DownClick;

    public override void UpButton()
    {
        base.UpButton();
        UpDownClick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        UpClick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public override void DownButton()
    {
        base.DownButton();
        UpDownClick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        DownClick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that UpButton() and DownButton() methods are executed also when you use the Up/Down arrow keys. You can avoid this by setting the InterceptArrowKeys property to false. Depending on your needs, you can override the OnTextBoxKeyDown method to have the required behavior.

Comment: I like this better than the coordinate checking method.

Comment: Thanks @SilviuBerce. Let me try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
private void TestNumericUpDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    if (me.X <= TestNumericUpDown.Controls[1].Width + 1)
        Console.WriteLine("EditBox");
    else if (me.Y <= TestNumericUpDown.Controls[1].Height / 2)
        Console.WriteLine("UpArrow");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("DownArrow");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but it needs a small fix. When you click on the 1 pixel Right border (not expected, but it could happen), the "UpArrow" or "DownArrow" will print to output, without clicking on the buttons. The fix is to add a check for the border click, after the first if condition: `else if (me.X >= numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Width + numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Left) Console.WriteLine("Right border");`

Comment: I think it's better to check if the coordinates are inside Up/Down buttons (`TestNumericUpDown.Controls[0]`) because the buttons can be aligned to Left or Right (RightToLeft and UpDownAlign properties).